# Where do I set the directories to in the cmake settings file in a clone of this github (https://github.com/johnBuffer/VerletSFML-Multithread)

Tags: cmake, sfml

I am trying to clone and run a github repo. (https://github.com/johnBuffer/VerletSFML-Multithread). It uses sfml so I downloaded it. In the cmake settings there are a couple directories that need to be set. I set the sfml dir to the sfml folder that I downloaded. I saved and tried to run it but I got an error about not finding the sfml config files. I can manually locate the file that it said it could not find so I am kind of confused. I also tried setting the dir to the fist folder that contains the file and it still didn't work.

There is one other cmake module path that needs to be changed but I don't know what to set it to. It is the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and it is set to a file that doesn't exist in the cloned project. (VerletSFML-Multithread/out/install/x64-Debug but there is nothing in the VerletSFML-Multithread/out folder) I don't really know what I am doing here, I come from making games in unity so all this is new to me. If anyone could help me with this I would appreciate it.

The error message:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       CMake Error at C:\Users\\source\repos\VerletSFML-Multithread\CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindSFML.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "SFML", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" (requested
  version 2) with any of the following names:

    SFMLConfig.cmake
    sfml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SFML" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SFML_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SFML"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Comment: You description - "sfml dir", "I can manually locate the file that it said it could not find" is quite vague. Which of the listed files you actually have on your machine? What is **absolute path** to that file? What is **exact name** of the variable **variable** you set? What **exact value** you have assigned to that variable?

Comment: "It is the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX and it is set to a file that doesn't exist in the cloned project." - CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX denotes the directory where the project **will be installed**. It doesn't need to be existed directory and doesn't need to contain any file.